# Reason of ORA-00604 - ORA-00904: on online Redefining

Tags: oracle

I made [Redefining Tables Online](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables007.htm#ADMIN11674) on a table . It worked fine but later when I tried to truncate the table I got this error .

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00904: "CURRENT_SCN": invalid identifier.
```

also I get the same error when I move the table:

```
 alter table tab1 move;
```

what is the reason of the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a DBA. But, I'm trying to help you out what I found over the internet.

`SCN` is **System Change Number**, which is used by Oracle to keep track of redo records.

**Possibilities:**

- Older Database version.
- Something went wrong during database backup.

**Possible Solution**

- Try out same thing in different version of Oracle.
- Restore your database.

**References:-**

- [ORA-00904: "COLUMN_NAME": invalid identifier](https://aprakash.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/silly-and-interesting-iii/)
- [Confusion about   recovery](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2325050)
- [SCN – What, why, and how?](https://orainternals.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/scn-what-why-and-how/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. for db version I am working on 11g, I dont think its old. for the backup , I didnt do any backup on the database.

Comment: You may not get absolute answer at `StackOverflow`. Post your question to dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: can you help me please to merge the question to dba?

Comment: We can't do anything now. Since, you initiated bounty. So, better post same question there.